# Position char at a specific memory address

Tags: rust, embedded, memory-address

I'm using Rust to write to VGA output. I'm absolutely new to this embedded field and I guess this is not only a Rust but also a general question.

I want to write different chars to the output screen:

```
let buff: *mut u8 = (0xb8000 + 1988) as *mut _;

unsafe {
    ptr::write(buff, (b'f'));
    ptr::write(buff, (b'o'));
    ptr::write(buff, (b'o'));
}
```

Doing this, I'm just seeing the last character (`o`) on the screen, since they are not written to another position.

How can I determine the position of the character when writing directly to a memory address?

I know of [Phil Opp's tutorial](https://os.phil-opp.com/printing-to-screen/) but I want to go on with my own solution, since it is a learning project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [Phil Opp's tutorial](https://os.phil-opp.com/printing-to-screen/), each character is 16-bits (2 bytes), which includes both the character and the color code.

Offset the buffer pointer by 2 bytes for each additional character you wish to output.

```
let buff: *mut u8 = (0xb8000 + 1988) as *mut _;

unsafe {
    ptr::write(buff, (b'f'));
    ptr::write(buff.offset(2), (b'o'));
    ptr::write(buff.offset(4), (b'o'));
}
```

I haven't tested out this myself.

Comment: thanks thats totaly right, but I'm wondering where you found ` each character is 16-bits (2 bytes)` ?

Comment: In the tutorial I linked, see "The VGA Text Buffer" section for what bits 0-15 stand for.